# Localization of strings in static lib

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, static-libraries

I have a project that uses a static library (SL). In that SL, there are a couple of strings I'd like to localize and the project includes all of the localization files. The localization works just fine when storing all text translations in the same file. The thing is that I'd like to separate the SL strings from the other strings. I have tried to put two different *.strings files (Localizable.strings and Localizable2.strings) in the language folder of interest but that did not work. I have also tried to use two *.strings file with the same name (Localizable.strings) but with different paths. It didn't work either. It seems that only one localization file is supported, right? Could anyone suggest a good way of doing this? I'm using SDK 3.2 beta 2.

Answer (score 15):

It is not possible to bundle it in a static lib, but you can create new bundle like "**MyStaticLibraryName.bundle**", put inside all localizations and use the code below instead "**NSLocalizedString()**". All you need to do: add a static library and resource bundle.

```
NSString *MyLocalizedString(NSString* key, NSString* comment) {
static NSBundle* bundle = nil;
if (!bundle) {
    NSString* path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyStaticLibraryName.bundle"];
    bundle = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] retain];
}

return [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:key table:nil];
}
```

Comment: For genstring to work with this setup the -s parameter must be used.

Answer (score 6):

Putting files with the same name intro one project never works, because in the resulting app they end up all in the same location. (Xcode doesn't preserve your directory structure.)

But you can put part of your localization into Localizable2.strings and then use:

NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"key", @"Localizable2", @"")

Answer (score 2):

Make the localizable string for the static library, then place that string file in a folder "YourLibraryResource".
Rename the folder "YourLibraryResource.bundle".

Now you include this bundle also in the project along with the library. Then use the code given by abuharsky.