# Localization doesn't work with Xcode 6 and dynamic library (jnilib)

Tags: java, xcode6, chromium-embedded, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

In my company, I need to localize our jni-library.
Our main application is written in Java and over [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) we are working with [CEF3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework)

(I know, there is a JCEF, but I need to resolve problem with CEF3)

The jnilib handles main menu like in this picture [image: chrome main menu]

I need to localize this menu, english and german.

What I did:

- Added Localizable.strings
- Added Strings in info tab on project settings
- Added Localizable.strings in copy bundle resources on target settings
- Renamed Localizable.strings and tried NSLocalizedStringFromTable
- Changed Localizable.strings encoding to UTF-16
- And of course tried all other "solutions" posted on stackoverflow and other webpages
- Tried this method: [Localization of static lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335664/localization-of-strings-in-static-lib)

But every time I only get the key as value.
If I print out BundlePath I get following path: (jdk home dir)

```
*/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin*
```

If I copy en.lproj and de.lproj to the bin dir (for test purposes), the localization is still not used.

I don't know what to do :/

I am working on MacOsX 10.10.3 with Xcode 6.3

Edit:
Code snipped, that doesn't work, too.

```
    NSString *path = @"pathtobundle/JNILIB.bundle";
    bundle = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] retain];

    NSString *tmp = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(key, nil, bundle, nil);
```

jnilib.bundle structure:

```
/JNILIB.bundle
   /en.lproj
      /Localized.strings
   /de.lproj
      /Localized.strings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution.

Here the link which helped me a lot: [static library and internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476840/static-library-and-internationalization)

Here my code:

```
NSString *MyLocalizedString(NSString* key, NSString* comment)
{

static NSBundle* bundle = nil;
if (!bundle) {

    NSString *path_tmp = @"pathToBundle/JNILIB.bundle";

    NSBundle *libraryBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path_tmp];
    NSString *langID        = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"preferredLanguage: %@", langID);

    NSString *path          = [libraryBundle pathForResource:langID ofType:@"lproj"];

    NSLog(@"libraryBundle : %@", path);

    bundle                  = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] retain];
}

return [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"Can't be found!" table:@"Localized"];
}
```

Bundle structure:

```
foo.bundle/
   Contents/
      Resources/
         en.lproj/
            Localized.strings
         de.lproj/
            Localized.strings
```